# Is asking for code review a suitable question?

Tags: discussion

There's a site specifically for [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). However, if my question is very Drupal specific, is asking questions like the following appropriate on *Drupal Answers*?

> I wrote function/module X, please review it for Drupal best practices

Comment: This doesn't really fit as an answer but there is a irc channel for code reviews #drupal-codereview (maybe an s at the end). It was fairly active when I left and they would be more than happy to review code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are asking for a full module, I would say that is not fine. It would be better you focus on specific parts, especially to avoid the question becomes a wall of code that would not probably be helpful to many users.

Differently, a single function would be more acceptable, especially when it is a hook implementation. A single function is probably more re-usable, and what reported could be useful to more users.

Generally speaking, a question like, "please review it for Drupal best practices" is not even a question, but a request. The OP should make clear why the code doesn't seem right, or for which reason the OP thinks the code could be optimized.

Answer (score 2):

A 'first' level of code review might be to use the code review module. It will review your module or really anything in the scope of where it's installed. Basically it will alert you to anything not up to drupal standards.

http://drupal.org/project/coder

I do this followed by opening up my bitbucket or github account repos to a few trusted associates.

Comment: Coder is certainly a great module, but in the context of reviewing ones _own_ code, I don't know what good excuse there is to not just set up your editor to do this. All my code follows the standards before they ever get into git, as my editor points out all problems that DrupalCS can find.

Comment: It is merely a first step.

Comment: Yes. My tone may not have been as friendly as it could have been, sorry about that. I up voted because it's a useful answer, even if my comment didn't make it sound like that. :)

Comment: No worries! I didn't take it as such.